# 504 timeout on AWS with nginx and gunicorn

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, nginx, gunicorn

I am running a python Django app on an AWS EC2 instance. It uses gunicorn and nginx to serve the app, the EC2 is behind an application load balancer. Occasionally I get 504 error where the entire EC2 instance becomes unreachable for everyone (including via SSH which I use all the time otherwise). I then need to restart everything which takes time.

I can replicate the error by overloading the app (e.g. uploading and processing a very large image), in that case, gunicorn worker times out (I see the timeout message in logs), 504 error appears and the instance becomes unreachable. I set my gunicorn to time out in 5 minutes (300 seconds) but it falls down quicker than that. There is nothing really useful in CloudWatch logs.

I am looking for ways to resolve this for all current and future cases. I.e., I want to have the situation where, if the site gets overloaded, it returns an error message as opposed to becoming completely unreachable for everyone. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many things to consider and test here in order to get what is a reason for this, but I think it is OOM(out of memory) mainly because you have to restart even to login in SSH.

> Nginx uses "event‑driven" approach to handle requests so a single worker of nginx can handle 1000s of req simultaneously. But Gunicorn on the other hand mostly(by default) uses sync worker which means a request will remain with a worker till it is processed.

When you put a large request your machine tries to process that request until an overflow occurs, mostly it will not get detected by any service running inside a machine. Just try to monitor memory by any monitoring tool in AWS or just SSH and use `htop` before calling the API.

In most cases with Django/gunicorn the culprit is oom.

**Edit:**

AFAIK You cannot capture(cache) an oom, the only thing you can do is aftermath i.e after system restart sees/var/logs/syslogs ... As I said monitor in AWS memory monitor(I don't have much experience with AWS).

And regarding the solution,

- you first increase the memory of your EC2 until you don't get an error to see how big the problem is.
- Then you optimise your application by profiling which part is actually taking this much memory. I haven't used any memory profiling so maybe you can tell me after which is better.
  The only thing you can do is optimise your application see common gotchas,  best practices, Query optimisations etc.

https://haydenjames.io/how-to-diagnose-oom-errors-on-linux-systems/
https://www.pluralsight.com/blog/tutorials/how-to-profile-memory-usage-in-python

Comment: Thanks, it does indeed look like it. Would you know if there is a way to fix it (capture error), or should I change technology altogether?

Comment: OK thank you. In the meantime, I moved away from gunicorn to uWSGI. With gunicorn, I could always replicate the problem by uploading a large image file and processing it. With uWSGI, that same file either gets uploaded or I get a 502 error which doesn't crash the instance (only I get it, not everyone). Looking promising so far.

Comment: also see https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/latest/faq.html#why-are-workers-silently-killed